# JsonResult returns null for Jquery .ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a Jquery .ajax post to an MVC action. This Action then should return a JsonResult. Currently, this JsonResult is "", however I want the return object to be filled with Json. Any help? Thanks!

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  dataType: 'json',
  url: url,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  traditional: true,
  data: JSON.stringify({ source: source }),
  success: function (data) {
debugger;
  }
});

public ActionResult PublishSource(string source)
{
    return Json(new {data = "test"});
}
```

Edit: Here's my current code below. Still having returned data in success method of .ajax being null.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;
        }
    });


public JsonResult PublishSource()
{
    var data = "test";
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: is the code entering into the success part. It could be possible there is an error and it is skipping the success and looking for the error function which isn't there obviously. Try changing `public ActionResult PublishSource(string source)` to public `JsonResult PublishSource(string source).` content Type is wrong as well change it to `contentType: 'application/json'`

Comment: in success method I'm getting data = ""

Comment: Im not sure what the problem is, but maybe its because you have traditional: true? I use JsonResults all ove rmy code and don't set that or the content type.

Comment: I added cache:false and took out traditional: true, but still no luck. I don't have this problem with returning Json data for Jquery Get, only for Jquery Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your controller action like below

```
public JsonResult PublishSource(string source)
{  
    var data="test";
    return Json(data,JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: I added this but still no luck. Here's my current code. Now the success method isn't hit.   

$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: url,
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify({ source: source }),
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
            }
        });

Comment: yes, I edited controller action too. I've put updated code up top

Answer (score 0):

Try this, see if it works:

```
return Json(new {dataObject = data}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and then on success you get the data like this:

```
        success: function (data) {
            debugger;

var returnedData = data.dataObject;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same or similar problem with JSON Result OK before returned by controller but NULL by the time it hit the ajax success callback.

Turned out not to be a problem with the call but the access modifier on the model which was getting converted to a JSON result by the controller. Set this to public and the result was no longer NULL in the success callback.

Hope this helps anyone in the same situation that have tried the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.NET as a default Serializer for serializing JSON instead of default Javascript Serializer:

This will handle the scenario of sending data if its NULL.

You need to write this in your action method:

```
return Json(data, null, null);
```

Note: 2nd and 3rd parameter null in above function is to facilitate overloads of Json method in Controller class.

Below is the code for JsonNetResult class.

```
public class JsonNetResult : JsonResult
{
    public JsonSerializerSettings SerializerSettings { get; set; }
    public Formatting Formatting { get; set; }

    public JsonNetResult()
    {
        SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
        JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("context");

        HttpResponseBase response = context.HttpContext.Response;

        response.ContentType = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(ContentType)
          ? ContentType
          : "application/json";

        if (ContentEncoding != null)
            response.ContentEncoding = ContentEncoding;

        JsonTextWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(response.Output) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };

        JsonSerializer serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(SerializerSettings);
        serializer.Serialize(writer, Data);

        writer.Flush();
    }
}
```

Also You need to add below code in BaseController if any in your project:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a NewtonSoft.Json.JsonNetResult object that serializes the specified object to JavaScript Object Notation(JSON).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="data"></param>
    /// <param name="contentType"></param>
    /// <param name="contentEncoding"></param>
    /// <returns>The JSON result object that serializes the specified object to JSON format. The result object that is prepared by this method is written to the response by the ASP.NET MVC framework when the object is executed.</returns>
    protected override JsonResult Json(object data, string contentType, System.Text.Encoding contentEncoding)
    {
        return new JsonNetResult
        {
            Data = data,
            ContentType = contentType,
            ContentEncoding = contentEncoding
        };
    }
```